# spreadjs with jhipster not working while generated project though online UI monolithic project

Tags: jhipster, spreadsheet, spreadjs, grapecity

I have created the project though jhipster online ui application and trying to use spreadjs . I am getting the error

ERROR in node_modules/@grapecity/spread-sheets-angular/dist/gc.spread.sheets.angular.ts:247:17 - error TS7029: Fallthrough case in switch.

247 case 'autoGenerateColumns':

The same application i created though cli - jhipster --skip-server --db=sql --auth=jwt it is working .

```
npm install @grapecity/spread-sheets@12
npm install @grapecity/spread-sheets-angular@12

import { SpreadSheetsModule } from '@grapecity/spread-sheets-angular';

added in app module

---------------------------- In Component .
import * as GC from '@grapecity/spread-sheets';
spread:any;
sheet:any;

ngOnInit(): void {
const ele = document.getElementById('viewFileData');
this.spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(ele);
this.sheet = this.spread.getSheet(0);
const activeSheet = this.spread.getActiveSheet();
activeSheet.setValue(10, 9, "Hashu");
}
```

I Added the code reference to produce the issue . Kindly check once .

Comment: Typescript compiler should not compile files in `node_modules/@grapecity`, so there are probably differnces between 2 projects generated that you should be able to identify by comparing webpack and typescript configuration. Once you found the differences,you should open an issue against https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-online/issues

Comment: thanks Gael , i have created the issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11976  , but they have closed the issue . it is not our side issue might with spread js. if i build  the cli  project using npm run build then again i am getting the  Error: Cannot find module 'terser-webpack-plugin' . If i install this plugin then i am getting the same issue which is occurring though online generated project . So something prob with this plugin or typescript compiler   , web pack issue .

Comment: I suggested you to open an issue once you have identified the problem but you didn't do this work so it's normal they closed the issue.